# What are some other uses for blockchain instead of money?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

What has blockchain been used for aside from money in the 10 years its been around?

I know things like etherium exist, but They don't seem be going anywhere, most of its value seams to come from the hope that someday someone will fond a use for smart contracts.

So has someone found a n alternative use for blockchain yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colored coins have used the blockchain to record the creation, ownership, and transfer of extrinsic assets other than bitcoin. Here's an excerpt from Mastering Bitcoin

> Colored coins are used to track digital assets as well as physical assets held by third parties and traded through colored coins certificates of ownership. Digital asset colored coins can represent intangible assets such as a stock certificate, license, virtual property (game items), or most any form of licensed intellectual property (trademarks, copyrights, etc.). Tangible asset colored coins can represent certificates of ownership of commodities (gold, silver, oil), land title, automobiles, boats, aircraft, etc.

This chapter mentions other use cases like Proof-of-Existence (Digital Notary), Kickstarter (Lighthouse), and Payment Channels (The Lightning Network). But I guess the later two still involve money.

Source: https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch12.asciidoc

Comment: Note: Using tokens to represent extrinsic assets (or otherwise reconcile extrinsic events) involves trusting an oracle which will input data to the chain, or otherwise honour the information stored in the chain. This is distinct from tokens/assets that are intrinsic to the chain, in that the oracle is a necessary trusted third party.